# How to desing an RPG system with regard to PVP

Tags: game-design, architecture, rpg

When you design a RPG system focused on PVE, one usually goes "mob of level X has Y hp and Z damage". How about when we do PVP with multiple classes?

Lets say we go Diablo, so we have STR/DEX/INT/VIT, how do you balance those between classes? Do I say:

- I want a fight to last 10 rounds on average (lets assume its turn based)
- barb starts with 300 hp, demon hunter 250 hp, wizard 200 hp

And now try to manipulate DPS / health using stats/skills so it matches the "10 round on average" by giving mage a mana shield an a lil bit more damage per fireball than barbarians melee attack? How would You approach this?

Comment: You work a lot. And you test. A lot. And you prepare to deal with the un-happy players that'll complain that the classes are unbalanced for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexandre commented, the best way to go about this is lots of work and testing. There is no simple solution or algorithm that can give you this answer. The tiniest change to any skill, stat, or other variable will directly affect the gameplay.

Your best bet is to just give it whatever values you think will lead to the gameplay you want and tweak them as you see necessary.